# Using spinOnce inside Services

Tags: ros, service, spin, rospy, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to know whether it is safe or bad practice to spin ROS inside a while loop that exists inside a service callback.  I am unable to use actions for this particular goal, and have confirmed that spinOnce inside the loop behaves as I expected, but before I go further I wanted to see if I was missing anything.  Basically, there will be another process that will break the while loop and return either true or false based on the purpose of the break.

Edit:
This question originally pertained to C++ packages, but has since also started to focus on python.  Basically, I may have a service that is called, but should not respond until another action has finished (communications).  I do not want this pause to effect other functions of the package, so I would like to find a way to have the service wait on responding, but spin ROS and let other callbacks react.  I see that AsyncSpinner may be a good solution, but not sure of one for python.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/118796/using-spinonce-inside-services/) by [orion](https://answers.ros.org/users/2818/orion/) on ROS Answers with karma: 213 on 2014-01-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

IIUC from the question, you need to service ROS callbacks during the execution of a service callback. Have you considered an asynchronous spinner as an alternative?. This wiki entry on [Callbacks and Spinning](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning#Multi-threaded_Spinning) is quite complete and might prove useful to your usecase.

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2014-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [orion](https://answers.ros.org/users/2818/orion/) on 2014-01-24**:
Example: I create a service.  When the service callback begins, I initiate something.  Until that something is finished, I do not send the response for the service. My thought was to have while loop on variable that the something would set to send the response. I will checkout the asynch spnner.